# Python 36 (Eclipse Oxygen, PyDev) crashes when reaching breakpoint

Tags: eclipse, python-3.6, pydev, null-pointer

Python 36 (on Windows 7, latest Anaconda with Python 36 under latest Eclipse Oxygen) is crashing whenever it reaches a breakpoint. The error is a 'classic' NULL pointer error.

`Unhandled exception at 0x000000001D8CF76D (python36.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

The (top) of the stack trace looks like this:

```
>   python36.dll!PyType_IsSubtype(_typeobject * a, _typeobject * b) Line 1358   C
    sip.pyd!000007fec602092d()  Unknown
    sip.pyd!000007fec6020897()  Unknown
    QtGui.pyd!000007fec6649d02()    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec(_object * spec, _iobuf *) Line 160 C
    python36.dll!_imp_create_dynamic_impl(_object * spec, _object * file, _object *) Line 1984  C
    python36.dll!_imp_create_dynamic(_object * module, _object * args) Line 289 C
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault(_frame * f, int throwflag) Line 3391  C
    pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp36-win_amd64.pyd!000007fed57869ac()    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName(_object * _co, _object * globals, _object * locals, _object * * args, __int64 argcount, _object * * kwnames, _object * * kwargs, __int64 kwcount, int kwstep, _object * * defs, __int64 defcount, _object * kwdefs, _object * closure, _object * name, _object * qualname) Line 4153  C
    python36.dll!call_function(_object * * * pp_stack, __int64 oparg, _object * kwnames) Line 4845  C
```

Not sure whether it is relevant, but my code is a Django 2.x application.
Any idea what is going on?
(I just ported this code from Python2)

Can I tell PyDev to *not* use precompiled code (pyd)?

**UPDATE**

Setting the env variable didn't help; I tried setting it for Eclipse, in the Python definition and in the Debug configuration.

Surprisingly deleting (renaming really) the `.pyd` didn't work either.

I tried to re-install PyDev and *not* build the debugger speedups this time (assuming this is how the .pyd are created), but the error remains.

`warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\364\data\779679999\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "solve" (at least work around) the problem by downgrading the `sip` package `conda install sip=4.18` (I had version 4.19.8)

I first tried to simply uninstall it with `conda uninstall sip ---force` (conda wanted to uninstall totally unrelated package as well), however that resulted in Qt5 errors.

Following the workaround auto-complete in debug mode broke down (not sure whether related).
Both the error and the fix for that case were absurd.

Completion error:

```
Error in fetching completionsTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", 
    line 1431, in do_it 
        completions_xml = pydevd_console.get_completions(frame, elf.act_tok)
  File "C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_console.py", 
    line 248, in get_completions
        return _pydev_completer.generate_completions_as_xml(frame, act_tok)
  File "C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\_pydev_completer.py", 
    line 167, in generate_completions_as_xml
        completions = pydevconsole.get_completions(act_tok, act_tok, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", 
    line 462, in get_completions
        interpreterInterface.interpreter.update(globals, locals)
  File "C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", 
    line 350, in update
        for key in dict_keys(self.ipython.user_ns):
NameError: name 'dict_keys' is not defined
```

`dict_keys` is not a method in `pydev_ipython_console_011.py` nor is it imported as far as I can tell.

My 'fix' was to add a `print(type(self.ipython.user_ns))` to check whether I can remove `dict_keys` and this miraculously fixed the problem. 
My assumption was that this triggered some recompilation of a `pyc`, but removing the print line made the error re-occur ... so I guess there is some memory corruption involved.

Comment: It seems an import was really missing (sorry about that). See: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/2984cea437e58ac1c606d7201c9cd1f585e453e3 for the fix (to be added to PyDev 6.3.4)

Comment: as @FabioZadrozny pointed out that adding:"from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants import dict_keys" to "plugins/org.python.pydev.core/pysrc/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py",the problem gone

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's breaking there, anyways, an easy workaround until this is sorted out is deleting the related .pyd in the pydev debugger (i.e.: just remove *.pyd inside the `_pydevd_frame_eval` folder where the debugger is located -- the actual .pyd file in this case is something as: `pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`).

That's in `eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_XXX/pysrc/_pydevd_frame_eval`.

Another option is setting an environment variable named `PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL` as `NO`.

Comment: Neither option worked. See my update above. Any other ideas?

Comment: But what error do you have now? (I mean, the original error pointed to `pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` in the stack which doesn't exist anymore, so, that can't be the error now right?) --- the last line you added now is a warning, not an error.

Comment: I did a diff between the error messages. The pydev line is missing (as expected) and also the addresses in the pyd lines are different, but the error is exactly the same. 
I also tried running the code in PyCharm, with the same result (except is crashes immediately, not when encountering a breakpoint)